# Sorting a list in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Here is the code on sorting any given list:

```
let rec sort lst =
   match lst with
     [] -> []
   | head :: tail -> insert head (sort tail)
 and insert elt lst =
   match lst with
     [] -> [elt]
   | head :: tail -> if elt <= head then elt :: lst else head :: insert elt tail;;
```

[Source: [Code](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual003.html)

However, I am getting an Unbound error:

```
Unbound value tail
# let rec sort lst =
   match lst with
     [] -> []
   | head :: tail -> insert head (sort tail)
 and insert elt lst =
   match lst with
     [] -> [elt]
   | head :: tail -> if elt <= head then elt :: lst else head :: insert elt tail;;
Characters 28-29:
     | head :: tail -> if elt <= head then elt :: lst else head :: insert elt tail;;
     ^
Error: Syntax error
```

Can anyone please help me understand the issue here?? I did not find `head` or `tail` to be predefined anywhere nor in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct, and compiles for me:

```
    Objective Caml version 3.11.1

# let rec sort lst = ...

val sort : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
val insert : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>

# sort [ 1 ; 3 ; 9 ; 2 ; 5 ; 4; 4; 8 ; 4 ] ;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 4; 4; 5; 8; 9]
```

Comment: But I did not understand what the pattern "head :: tail" means. Can you please explain?

Comment: The type list is a built-in type defined as having two constructors. One is the empty list `[]`. The other is the cons cell `::`. The pattern matchings you have written are no different from the pattern matchings you could write for types you would have defined yourself, except that they use the built-in 0-ary constructor [] and binary ::.

Comment: In the pattern `head :: tail`, the variable `head` represents the first element of the list, and `tail` the rest of the list.

Comment: Compiles and runs with 3.10 as well.

Comment: Hi,

I am still getting the error : http://www.easy-share.com/1910132443/Error.bmp

Can you please help me find out the reason?

Regards,
darkie

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Pascal said, the list type is defined as:

```
type 'a list = [] | :: of 'a * 'a list
```

and that's what you are matching your list `lst` against.

Comment: Hi,

I am still getting the error : http://www.easy-share.com/1910132443/Error.bmp

Can you please help me find out the reason?

Regards,
darkie

Answer (score 1):

The symbol “|“ is the horizontal line symbol, it is not l character and the -> are the minus symbol and the bigger symbol. I think you copied and pasted the segment of code in the website of Inria. Please check and rewrite the special symbols. I tested it and it works well.

Comment: I think you mean "vertical"

Answer (score 0):

Head and tail need not to be defined. They are matched from 'list' you give.